# my Dropdown is not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery for Dropdown but there is some error and beacuse of which it is not working properly.
my html is

```
<div id="maintain_execute_suite" style="margin-left: 169px; margin-top: 102px;">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-sm-3">

                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="btn-group">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                <span data-bind="label">Select One Suite</span>&nbsp;<span class="caret"></span>
                            </button>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Another item</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">This is a longer item that will not fit properly</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

and jquery is

```
$( document.body ).on( 'click', '.dropdown-menu li', function( event ) {

        var $target = $( event.currentTarget );

        $target.closest( '.btn-group' )
           .find( '[data-bind="label"]' ).text( $target.text() )
           .end()
           .children( '.dropdown-toggle' ).dropdown( 'toggle' );

        return false;

     });
```

when i am clicking on menu then it is opening but it is not showing the value after selecting options from list.  i have posted it into fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cvhpac4m/5/
I am not able to insert js and css of bootstrap
[image]

Comment: Please fix js errors in jsfiddle provided

Comment: Your code works. All you need is to include jquery and bootstrap in your fiddle. Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/anpsmn/cvhpac4m/3/)

Comment: but in my html it is not working and it is giving error in firebug. I have attached image.

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/cvhpac4m/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you included jQuery in your HTML?

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

Also check if any relative links to jQuery (Example, a link without http: `src="//code...` ) is not breaking on your local machine.

Here is my exact code not in a fiddle that I open on my local machine without errors.:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Generic</title>
    <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

    <div id="maintain_execute_suite" style="margin-left: 169px; margin-top: 102px;">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-sm-3">

                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="btn-group">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                <span data-bind="label">Select One Suite</span>&nbsp;<span class="caret"></span>
                            </button>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Another item</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">This is a longer item that will not fit properly</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $( document.body ).on( 'click', '.dropdown-menu li', function( event ) {

            var $target = $( event.currentTarget );

            $target.closest( '.btn-group' )
            .find( '[data-bind="label"]' ).text( $target.text() )
            .end()
            .children( '.dropdown-toggle' ).dropdown( 'toggle' );

            return false;

        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've updated my answer with the full HTML page outside of the fiddle.